# C++ binding function to a pointer

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

in my project i want to bind a function with this signature:

```
template <typename... Args> void* functionA(int a, int b, Args&& ... args){
    ...
}
```

to a pointer... So here is how i try:

```
    ...
    void** new_address_ptr;
    *new_address_ptr = (void*) &functionA;
    ...
```

However this produces me this error : **address of overloaded function with no contextual type information**

I need the `void** new_address_ptr;` for my further execution but i just can not figure out how to bind it...

Comment: why do you need that `void**` in the first place? There are nicer ways to store function pointers

Comment: JNI allows me to rebind java static methods only to void** pointer... I cannot change that, sadly

Answer (score 2):

`functionA` is not the name of a function, it's the name of a template. To turn it into the name of a function (which will be an instantiation of a template), add appropriate template arguments. For example, if you want to call `functionA` with an `int` and `std::string &`, do this:

```
*new_address_ptr = reinterpret_cast<void*>(&functionA<int, std::string&>);
```

However, this smells of problems. You'll need to provide the template arguments up front (of the correct type), and since the function uses forwarding references, finding the correct type may not be easy: you'll need to use lvalue references to enable calling the function with lvalues.

Not to mention the fact that storing a pointer to a function in a `void *` is not even guaranteed to work, and depends on whether your compiler supports it.

---

I used `reinterpret_cast` because C-style casts are best avoided in C++, since it requires detailed inspection of the types involved to realise what exactly they do.

Comment: what about the varargs argument there ? can i reinterpret cast to varargs ?

Comment: @AksimElnik Can you clarify? The resulting function(s) have no variadic arguments. For each arity (and type combination) of arguments, you get a different function.

Comment: @AksimElnik afaik varargs is a compiletime concept, at runtime any function takes a fixed number of parameters. On the other hand a function pointer is something that you can only have at runtime. I have the impression that you are mixing things that dont work together.

Comment: ahh, i see... thank you for your explanation guys... seems like i cannot instantiate a template with variadic arguments, am i right ?

Comment: @AksimElnik not sure if I understand that last comment. You can instantiate a variadic template by passing a fixed number of template parameters, as for ex. in  `functionA<int, std::string&>`

Comment: @AksimElnik A template such as yours (with a variadic number of template parameters) produces a different instantiation for each list of template arguments (normally deduced from function arguments). So no, these result in different functions. There are also the C-style variadics (like `printf` uses), but those are best avoided in C++. In all, this question seems to be a bit of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/201677).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that, because there is no such function as `functionA` exist.
You'd have to instantiate the template and only then get address of that function.

Comment: `*new_address_ptr = functionA;` only works if i have instantiated my template , right ??? How do i instantiate it though

Comment: it would work if `functionA` was a regular function, not a template

Comment: You *do* need a cast for assigning to a `void *`. Function pointers don't conver to object pointers (or vice versa) automatically.

Comment: @Angew I thought so too, but when I tried with ms compiler it works with no warnings, however clang does error out.

Comment: @Pavel You cannot trust the MS compiler with anything related to standard compliance.